How to mplement event streaming using golang github.com/r3labs/sse/v2
I tried the below program to implement event streaming using github.com/r3labs/sse/v2  but which is not working as expected , it is going to infinite loop looks like.
What I need is to implement event streaming in a service running in a kubernetes pod with reconnection strategy so that I will not miss any events. And also it should start streaming from the last eventID in my DB record.
https://localhost:8080/events?tail=true gives below result using a curl command
lasteventID:eyJkZWxpdmVyeS1hY2NvdW50cyI6eyItMI0MDQ3ODUsIjAiOjEwNCwiMSI6NjQsIjIiOjQ5LCIzIjo3MX19
event:message
data:{}
lasteventID:eyJkZWxpdmVyeS1hLTIiOjE2ODYxOTI1OTY1MjUsIjAiOjEwNCwiMSI6NjUsIjIiOjQ5LCIzIjo3MX19
event:message
data:{}
What I tried here is below. I need a proper reconnect strategy with LastEventID in headers to stream from the last event stored before reconnecting.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/r3labs/sse/v2"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    go StreamEvents(ctx, database)

}
func StreamEvents(ctx context.Context, database *mongonative.Database) {

    client := sse.NewClient("https://localhost:8080/events?tail=true")
    client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "<token>"
    client.Headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
    err = getLatestMarker(ctx, database, client, "myevents")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to get marker : %v", err)
    }

    eventCh := make(chan *sse.Event, 4)

    go func() {
        maxRetries := 5
        retries := 0
        for {
            err := client.SubscribeChanWithContext(context.Background(), "", eventCh)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("failed to subscribe : %v", err)
                if errors.Is(err, ErrStreamUnauthorized) {
                    retries++
                    if retries >= maxRetries {
                        logger.LogV2f(ctx, logger.Log, "reached maximum number of retries")
                        break
                    }
                } else {

                    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
                    fmt.Println("reconnecting to stream after connection failure with latest eventID")
                    err := getLatestMarker(ctx, database, client, "myEvents")
                    if err != nil {
                        logger.LogV2f(ctx, logger.Log, "failed to get marker for re-connect : %v", err)
                    }
                }
                continue
            }
            err = getLatestMarker(ctx, database, client, "myEvents")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("failed to get marker for re-streaming : %v", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {

        var ed models.Data
        for event := range eventCh {
            fmt.Println("Received event with event ID : %s", event.ID)
            // save events to DB
            evStatus := models.EventStatus{EventID: string(event.ID), Type: "myEvents", LastProccessedAt: time.Now()}
            utils.UpdateEventStatus(ctx, database, evStatus)
        }
    }()
}

func getLatestMarker(ctx context.Context, database *mongonative.Database, client *sse.Client, evType string) (err error) {
    collection := database.Collection(utils.EventStatus)
    var markerRecord models.EventStatus
    err = collection.FindOne(ctx, primitive.M{"type": evType}).Decode(&markerRecord)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to get marker : %v", err)
    }

    if markerRecord.EventID != "" {
        logger.LogV2f(ctx, logger.Log, "will start streaming from the eventID : %s", markerRecord.EventID)
        client.Headers["Last-Event-ID"] = markerRecord.EventID
    }
    return

}

